# StringBuffer or StringBuilder for my query

Tags: sql, string, optimization, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

I understand first one is synchronized  and the later one is unsynchronized with faster response time.

I am using `StringBuffer` for appending a SQL query. Transferring to `StringBuilder` would make it faster(*My question is especially in regards to SQL*)?

Is it advisable to use `StringBuilder` around SQl query appending?

**My Current Code**

```
public boolean saveData (Connection conn,MyObject) throws SQLException {
..
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try{
StringBuffer sSubQry = new StringBuffer();                      
sSubQry.append (" select ID, STATEID, TYPEID, LANGID, SEQ, ");
sSubQry.append (" SECTIONSEQ, CODE, NAME, INPUTNAME, ");
sSubQry.append (" .., .., ..,");
sSubQry.append (" .., .., ..,");
..
..
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sSubQry.toString());
rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
while (rs.next ())
 {
 ..
 }
}
```

By transferring it to `StringBuilder` have any `+ve` or `-ve` effects

```
public boolean saveData (Connection conn,MyObject) throws SQLException {
..
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try{
StringBuilder sSubQry = new StringBuilder();                        
sSubQry.append (" select ID, STATEID, TYPEID, LANGID, SEQ, ");
sSubQry.append (" SECTIONSEQ, CODE, NAME, INPUTNAME, ");
sSubQry.append (" .., .., ..,");
sSubQry.append (" .., .., ..,");
..
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sSubQry.toString());
rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
while (rs.next ())
 {
 ..
 }
}
```

Comment: It's more advisable to not use SQL query appending.  Why do you need to do it this way?

Comment: @Siyual My query is too long

Comment: Check [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Comment: @SomeJavaGuy I highly doubt your query is too long to fit in a `string` variable.  But regardless, you should use a prepared statement, or possibly a stored procedure.

Comment: Is the constructed query actually different each execution?

Comment: @Siyual I would advise strongly against a stored procedure. Unless there is a highly compelling reason, they are a bad idea: they can't be easily: tested, deployed, ported, maintained or even written.

Comment: @Bohemian With all due respect, I disagree.  Stored Procedures are far easier to maintain when they are separated from the application code.  If a change is needed, one would only need to modify it at the proc level, rather than recompiling/redeploying the application code.

Comment: @Siyual firstly, recompiling and deploying app code in a modern dev environment should be a one-click operation at the end of a thoroughly tested, fully automated, build pipeline. Secondly, exactly how do you run fully automated unit tests on a SP? I used to be a "database guy" and a good one, so I know what you're feeling. Consider that a database does a few things well - see [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) - and you should let it do that stuff. It *can* do a bunch of other things (like SPs), but modern app code does them way better and easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all being done in a single thread, so yes, a `StringBuilder` is fine (but see comments about whether it's appropriate to construct SQL this way at all).

Whenever you have a sequence of steps like this, where you create a local variable, and then never pass a reference to it to any other method, and you never return it, you can be sure only the current thread can access it.

(Usually, if you're passing something to another thread, you'll be aware that that's what you're doing.)

Answer (score 2):

`sSubQry` belongs to the `saveData` method scope, so you can safely use a `StringBuilder`.

`StringBuffer` may be useful when a class instance member can be shared by different threads.